# How to make a full-width jumbotron?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

If you look at the [twitter-bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) website their jumbotron touches their `nav-header`. That's what I'm trying to replicate.

I added it to the top of my valuations index like so:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Values <small>subjective, put here whatever inspires you. </small></h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

I also tried it without the container even though bootstrap says,

*"To make the jumbotron full width, and without rounded corners, place it outside all .containers and instead add a .container within."*

Is it because my application.html.erb is broken down into columns and so the jumbotron will only expand to the width of the `col-md-9`?

```
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
<% end %>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <% if current_user.present? %>
        <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried putting in its own partial but then there was padding between the `nav-header` and the `jumbotron` that I don't want. Like I said I want it like the [bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/components/). The other problem with a partial is I'd need a lot of them because I want to change the words in the `jumbotron` depending on the page.

How can we do it like bootstap?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because whatever is rendered in the `<%= yield%>` gets wrapped in `col-md-9`. You can either:

1. close `col-md-9` in views where you want to have the full-width jumbotron, and re-open it again in the footer.
2. don't use col-md-9 in `application.rb` if most of your views need to be expanding to full width.

## EDIT:

To avoid repetition, you can paste the jumbotron styling in between your `layouts/header` and `container-fluid`, and use a variable for populating it with page-specific text. Here is what I mean:

```
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag(:div, msg, class: "alert alert-info") %>
<% end %>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <p class="text-center">
  <%= @jumbotext %> <!-- this variable should be assigned in your controller action-->
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container"> <!-- check this too. not sure why you have two containers-->
    <div class="col-md-9"> 
      ...
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimitry_N I have a sidebar like bootstrap too so removing `col-md-9` would force the sidebar to go underneath the content. I'm confused by your 1. Are you saying add `col-md-9` to every view and then just put the `jumbotron` above it? I can see that working, but wouldn't that be a lot duplicating?

Comment: no, you can keep the `col-md-9` in the `application` layout, but if a view needs to have this full-width jumbotron, start it with `</div><!--end_col-md-9--> then do the add the `jumbotron`, then re-open the `col-md-9`.Take a look: http://www.bootply.com/jbMuxsnSZH

Comment: Dimitry_N every page will have the jumbotron (with different wording inside it). I'm thinking I have to remove it from application.rb and put it in the views under jumbotron. You think thats the best way?

Comment: @RubyonRailsBeginner ahhh, I see what you mean now. One last question before I revise my answer. Will the position of the jumbotron always be the same across all views?

Comment: Yea and with the method I mentioned above I can't get it to be full-width tho unless I move `container-fluid` & `container` below it in application.rb but when i do that the sidebar drops below the content again errrrrr

Comment: @RubyonRailsBeginner Got it. Give me a few. Updating my answer