# How to change jumbotron text per page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

In application.html.erb I know I need to use this:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <p class="text-center">
    <%= @jumbotext %> <!-- this variable should be assigned in controller action-->
  </p>
</div>
```

But what do I put in the controller? Do I put it in the application controller or do I put it in each of the other controllers?

Once whatever needs to go in the controller is there where do I add text so that the jumbotron renders different text depending on what page is clicked on, just like how [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron) has it on there site?

This question was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29264937/how-to-make-a-full-width-jumbotron).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of ways you can resolve this problem.
Main question is, how much versions of jumbotron content are there? Here are two suggestions.

## Solution 1: Before action

You can use a [before action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) in your applications controller to assign some default value.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_jumbotext

  private

  def set_jumbotext
    @jumbotext = "Default value"
  end
end
```

and then assign a different value in controller actions where it's needed.

## Solution 2: Content for

You could also avoid using an instance variable and inject HTML from view directly to your layout using [content_for](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method) helper

application.html.erb

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <p class="text-center">
    <%= yield :jumbotron %>
  </p>
</div>
```

create_user_view.html.erb

```
<h1> Normal view content </h1>

<% content_for :jumbotron do %>
  This will be embedded in jubotron.
<% end %>
```